# How to get same rows index in a list?

Tags: python, numpy, duplicates

I have a numpy array like this:

```
[[0 1 0]
 [1 2 1]
 [2 2 1]
 [3 0 0]
 [4 0 1]
 [5 1 2]
 [6 0 1]
 [7 1 0]
 [8 1 2]]
```

First column is the indexes and other two columns are location x,y.

I want to get a list of indexes that have same x,y locations.

For example for above input the output can be like group of indexes in each row:

```
groups = [[0,7],
          [1,2],
          [4,6],
          [5,8],
          [3]]
```

So each row represents one group of indexes having the same location x,y. 5 groups in which 4 groups have 2 members, whereas notice that the last row shows an index 3 only. This group has only one index i.e. 3.

How can I achieve this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out:

```
lis = [[0 ,1, 0],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [2, 2, 1],
 [3, 0, 0],
 [4, 0, 1],
 [5, 1, 2],
 [6, 0, 1],
 [7, 1, 0],
 [8, 1, 2]]

dic = {}

for x,y,z in lis:
    if dic.get((y,z)):
        dic[(y,z)].append(x)
    else:
        dic[(y, z)] = [x]
final_list = [dic[key] for key in dic.keys()]

print(final_list)
```

Comment: excellent! worked like charm. Just converted my numpy array to list and used your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want functionality like a group by operation. Your best bet is to convert it into a pandas dataframe and then do a group by.

```
import pandas as pd

a = [[0, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1], 
     [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 1], [5, 1, 2], 
     [6, 0, 1], [7, 1, 0], [8, 1, 2]]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns =['index', 'x', 'y'])
grouped_df = df.groupby(['x', 'y']).aggregate(lambda x: tuple(x)).reset_index()

print(grouped_df)
```

**Output:**

```
   x  y   index
0  0  0    (3,)
1  0  1  (4, 6)
2  1  0  (0, 7)
3  1  2  (5, 8)
4  2  1  (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Other option using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
for x, y, z in array:
  res[(y,z)].append(x)
```

Then you can call

```
print(list(res.values()))
#=> [[0, 7], [1, 2], [3], [4, 6], [5, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In simplest way without using any package;

```
l = [[0, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [2, 2, 1],
 [3, 0, 0],
 [4, 0, 1],
 [5, 1, 2],
 [6, 0, 1],
 [7, 1, 0],
 [8, 1, 2]]

s = [(l1[0], l1[1:]) for l1 in l]
s = [[x for x, y in s if y == b] for a, b in s]
s = [y for x, y in enumerate(s) if y not in s[:x]]
print(s)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 7], [1, 2], [3], [4, 6], [5, 8]]
```